# Alternative for deprecated classes in docx4j 11+

Tags: docx4j

I was using ListSer and SerContent classes earlier when I was using docx4j 6+. Now as part of a security check we decided to updated docx4j to 11.1.3 and found these classes are missing.

Below is the case where we were using it:

```
SerContent ctChartSer = null;
ListSer ctChartSers = null;
List<SerContent> ctChartSersList = null; //= ctChartSers.getSer();
CTTextBody body = null;

String typeOfChart = "";
if (object instanceof CTBarChart) {
    typeOfChart = "bar";
    ctChartSers = (CTBarChart) object;
    ctChartSersList = ctChartSers.getSer();
} else if (object instanceof CTBar3DChart) {
    typeOfChart = "bar";
    ctChartSers = (CTBar3DChart) object;
    ctChartSersList = ctChartSers.getSer();
} else if (object instanceof CTLineChart) {
    typeOfChart = "line";
    ctChartSers = (CTLineChart) object;
    ctChartSersList = ctChartSers.getSer();
} else if (object instanceof CTAreaChart) {
    typeOfChart = "area";
    ctChartSers = (CTAreaChart) object;
    ctChartSersList = ctChartSers.getSer();
} else if (object instanceof CTPieChart) {
    typeOfChart = "pie";
    ctChartSers = (CTPieChart) object;
    ctChartSersList = ctChartSers.getSer();
} else if (object instanceof CTPie3DChart) {
    typeOfChart = "pie";
    ctChartSers = (CTPie3DChart) object;
    ctChartSersList = ctChartSers.getSer();
} else if (object instanceof CTDoughnutChart) {
    typeOfChart = "doughnut";
    ctChartSers = (CTDoughnutChart) object;
    ctChartSersList = ctChartSers.getSer();
}
```

Basically I want a variable to store the chart series content. Can anyone help to replace or a change in approach?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at org.docx4j.dml.chart.CTPieChart (*is this the package you are talking about?*), [there is](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/docx4j-parent-11.1.3/docx4j-openxml-objects/src/main/java/org/docx4j/dml/chart/CTPieChart.java#L120):

```
 public List<CTPieSer> getSer()
```

I haven't checked the other classes you reference, but I'd expect the getSer method to be in them as well.  These classes should be in your docx4j-openxml-objects jar.

By the way, looks like it would be good to have these classes implement a common 'getSer' interface.

Comment: Yes Jason, I was referring to the common class like "import org.docx4j.dml.chart.SerContent;". We used to have this earlier in docx4j 6+ where we can store the series content based on the instance of the each object in List<Object> objects = chart.getJaxbElement().getChart().getPlotArea()
                    .getAreaChartOrArea3DChartOrLineChart();